# Cannot resolve keyword 'created' into field. Choices are: date, id, post, user, user_id?

Tags: python, django

Hi I am trying to add a field into my model called 'created' however I get the following error:
Cannot resolve keyword 'created' into field. Choices are: date, id, post, user, user_id

Traceback:

```
FieldError at /home/
Cannot resolve keyword 'created' into field. Choices are: date, id, post, user, user_id

Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\josep\beginnerProjects\tutorial\accounts\templates\base.html, error at line 0
```

cmd/terminal:

```
"Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'created' into field. Choices are: date, id, post, user, user_id
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
   template_name = ('home/home.html')

   def get(self, request):
      form = HomeForm()
      posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('created')

      args = {'form': form, 'posts': posts}
      return render(request, self.template_name, args)

   def post(self, request):
      form = HomeForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.user = request.user
        post.save()
        text = form.cleaned_data['post']
        form = HomeForm()
        return redirect('home:home')

      args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
      return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Comment: you made the migrations, but did you migrated by running `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: I did use python manage.py migrate

Comment: I believe Vaibhav answer has a good point, can you connect to the db and run a select query to see the fields?

Comment: unsure on how to do that

Comment: `python manage.py dbshell` to connect your db and check your table

Comment: I did .tables and got this:
sqlite> .tables
accounts_userprofile        auth_user_user_permissions
auth_group                  django_admin_log
auth_group_permissions      django_content_type
auth_permission             django_migrations
auth_user                   django_session
auth_user_groups            home_post
sqlite>

Comment: got it to work..i just deleted the field and created it again. thanks for the help!